# Why won't Cocoa Pods gem update?

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

Anyone know why 'sudo gem update cocoapods' would return 'Nothing to update', even though I'm running 0.27.1, which is not the latest (0.28.0)?

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?  Don't just downvote me -- help me to do better next time.  I know I don't have a lot of data here, but there's just not much to it.  The only output I got was 'Nothing to update'.  Should have mentioned that I'm running Mac 10.9.1, though.

Comment: Hopefully my upvote will provide you with some validation. Ran into this problem myself. The proposed answer below worked btw.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say just reinstall the gem:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods; sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

While your going to update your pods you just focus on the below terminal commands.These commands is more than enough for update our pods. Hope it may help you.

```
    $sudo gem update —system
    $sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
    $sudo gem install cocoapods
    $pod setup
    $cd <project path>
    $pod init
    add files(frameworks)($pod outdated- if already pod exists)
    $pod install
    $pod update(if you need)
```